# When to use iOS device token when sending push notifications through FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm confused about the implementation of cloud messaging through FCM. To send an iOS device a remote (push) notification, an iOS device token is needed for APNs. However, a Firebase app doesn't interface with APNs, it interfaces with FCM, which interfaces with APNs. But to send a push notification (or message) to any client through FCM requires an FCM token. Does this mean that the iOS device token is not needed for a Firebase app to send push notifications to iOS devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only an FCM token is required to send a message to a device.  There is no Apple-specific data required.  Firebase handles the details of each underlying push notification system.

Comment: How does FCM use APNs without knowing the iOS device token? Does it get it on its own or does it not need to know?

Comment: Why are you asking?  Is something not working the way you expect?

Comment: I just want to understand this API better, that's all. If somebody ever asks me this question, I don't want my answer to be "I don't know, it just works."

Comment: You can examine the source code to see how everything works.  It's all open source.  I think you'll find that the SDK manages all the Apple specific details, including whatever needs to be done with apns. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Comment: @acidgate I think what's happening is under the hood firebase is mapping your FCM to APNS and when it needs to communicate with apple it retrieves it.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase uses method swizzling to automatically map your FCM token to your APNs token, as explained in the Firebase Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#token-swizzle-disabled) (or see images below).

[image]

[image]